# Add a model that uses money-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, currency, money-rails

I want to create a model named "Donations", which has an attribute named "amount" which will be utilizing money-rails gem. Please guide me how to initiate the process.
Will it be generated similarly, just need to add "monetize" in that model? Would be helpful if some pro could elaborate its working.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a model in a similar way we create other models, inside the model use the `monetize` macro to set the attribute as a `Money` object.

make sure the column you want to use as a Money object must be postfix by `_cents`. This will add the `amount` attribute to each `Donation` object which is `Money` object

```
class Donation
  monetize :amount_cents 
end
```

If you want to use any other column like column name without `_cents` as postfix, you have to provide `as` argument with a string value, make sure column name and string value passed to `as` argument must be different.

```
class Donation
  monetize :amount, as: 'contribution'
end
```

Read [this](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#activerecord) ActiveRecord section of readme to understand it.